# Node error on compile React - internal/buffer:959

Tags: reactjs

I recently got an error when compiling React projects. I launch the app normally, it launches my APP. But sometimes it happens to show the attached error and the application stops. So I need to run the start command again.

I tried removing node_modules folder and installing again, but it didn't work. I couldn't find the reason.

Any suggestion?

[Print ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGMsu.jpg)

Comment: Can you include the error in the question? Images of text are not particularly helpful or efficient.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.